# запуск программы через node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, exec

Когда я запускаю 1 программу таким образом, я получаю ошибку: "Configuration file was not found" (При обычном запуске, программа работает нормально). Т.е программа начинает запускаться, но потом я получаю эту ошибку. Из-за чего может возникать?

```js
const filePath = 'путь';
require('child_process').execFile(filePath);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Есть вероятность, что программа подразумевает запуск с опеределённым рабочим (текущим) каталогом. Попробуйте задать его явно:

```js
const filePath = 'путь';
const fileDir = require('path').dirname(filePath); // или просто задайте путь строкой
require('child_process').execFile(filePath, { cwd: fileDir });
```

Comment: спасибо. Все начало работать!